# Can't retrieve Android custom class arraylist data

Tags: java, android, arraylist

I have a simple custom arraylist class with 3 variables, and I've stored data from SQLite into them just like this:

```
    List<String> nomess= produtoDAO.getAllProductsId(id);
    Cursor allrows = produtoDAO.getAllDataForSpinner(id);

    if (allrows.moveToFirst()) {
        do {

            String ID = allrows.getString(0);
            String NAME = allrows.getString(1);
            String PLACE = allrows.getString(2);
            SpinnerObject data = new SpinnerObject(ID, NAME, PLACE);
            nomes.add(data);

        } while (allrows.moveToNext());
    }
```

**SpinnerObject class:**

package object;

```
public class SpinnerObject {

private String id;
private String nome;
private String id_cliente;

public SpinnerObject(String _id, String _nome, String _id_cliente)
{
    _id = id;
    _nome = nome;
    _id_cliente = id_cliente;
}
}
```

I'd like to know how I could get the stored info and convert to a string array list now. I tried nomes.get(position) but it doesn't seem to work (I get the error **object.SpinnerObject cannot be cast to java.util.List**).

Please help! Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I get the error object.SpinnerObject cannot be cast to java.util.List

Probably you are trying to cast `SpinnerObject` object to `List` because `nomes.get(position)` should return  `SpinnerObject` class object instead of `List`.

Get value from List as:

```
SpinnerObject objSpinner=nomes.get(position);
```

Create getter method in `SpinnerObject` class:

```
public class SpinnerObject {
...

 public String getId(){
  return this.id;
 }

 public String getName(){
  return this.nome;
 }

}
```

Now use `objSpinner.getId()`, `objSpinner.getName()` to access all values

Comment: Hello, thank you for your answer! Unfortunately it is not working, could I be doing something wrong? I used a Log.d and the objSpinner returned this: **"object.SpinnerObject@3d6f4358OU:"** I tried to convert the objSpinner to a list too, and i got the same error :(

Comment: @DiegoFortes: i hope you have id,name, and place varaibles in SpinnerObject class so.  use `objSpinner` to access these variables like objSpinner.id,objSpinner.name

Comment: I do have those variables within SpinnerObject! Should I make getters and setters? Maybe the SpinnerObject's variables should be array lists as well?

Comment: Thanks for your attention, but unfortunately it's just not working the way I need it to work yet :( It should return me more than one item, (all items I've added in the While, the whole arraylist) and it is not. I will try to seek a few other solutions to adress this problem!

Comment: @DiegoFortes Are you really trying to convert a List of object to a list of string?? This is what you have asked in the question.

Comment: @DiegoFortes: what you mean by it's not working? your question is very clear as posted and my answer is according to user question